# Magento 2 Forgot Password page incorrect captcha

Tags: magento2, customer, magento2.2, forms, captcha

In my magento site I have enabled Captcha for Forgot Password form of custom theme, but when I try to reset password with providing correct captcha code in the field, even then it shows "Incorrect Captcha" after refreshing & redirecting to same page.

I'm using [magento-2-social-login](https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-social-login)

No warnings/errors either in the client or server.

Any suggestions please?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've adding custom script that can be reloading the captcha image.

**In:**

> /app/design/frontend/name_space/theme_name/Magento_Customer/templates/form/forgotpassword.phtml

**Custom script:**

```
jQuery( "captcha-button-selector" ).trigger( "click" );
```

Then it's solved my problem.

@Kumar thanks.

Comment: Welcome @mahmoudismail I also edited my answer.

Comment: captcha-button-selector   what is this.. i used this code but not working

Comment: @Maruti_magento2 `captcha-button-selector` is the `button class name` or `Button Id`

Answer (score 3):

After every action Magento does refresh captcha session so if any Ajax URL run and you open your forgot password then at that time captcha session will be changed that's why you are getting error. Just click on reload captcha button and then refill again to proceed successfully.

You can add scripts to reload captcha when that from open so you will not get error again.

You can manually trigger reload by this

```
$('.action.captcha-reload'). trigger ('click');
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the whole script. I have added jQuery `bind` concept to reload captcha when forgot password page is loaded.

Here is the path to add the below script.

> /app/design/frontend/NAMESPACE/YOURTHEME/Magento_Customer/templates/form/forgotpassword.phtml

```
<script>
require(["jquery"], function ($) {
    // Reload captcha when page loaded
    $(window).bind("load", function() {
        // Use setTimeout to trigger captcha reload. 
        $(".action.captcha-reload").trigger("click");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, check if you enabled default captcha or not. If it is enabled then Disable that, then it will work.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/173845)

Comment: This one solved that error for me.